# Ruby on Rails – admin comment approval on a blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, blogs

I am creating a blog that has pins and comments. I am wondering how to create a system whereby the admin can approve comments on blogs before users can view them.

First I tried adding a boolean field called `pinreview` to my comments model:

`comment.rb`

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pin

  scope :approved, ->{
    where(:pinreview => false)
  }
  scope :pending, -> {
    where(:pinreview => true)
  }

  scope :newest, -> {
    order("created_at desc")
  }
end
```

```rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:pin_id])
    @comment = @pin.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))

    redirect_to pin_path(@pin)
  end

  def destroy
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:pin_id])
    @comment = @pin.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    redirect_to pin_path(@pin)
  end
end
```

I have defined the user types through enums:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  enum access_level: [:guest, :admin]
  has_many :pins

  def admin
    admin?
  end

  def guest
    guest?
  end

end
```

And in my view I have been trying things like this:

`pins/show.html.erb`

```
...
    - if current_user && current_user.admin? ? @pin.comments = Comment.all : @pin.comments = Comment.where(:approved => false) 
...
```

The pinned post shows, but not the user comments, and when logged in as admin, no space to approve comments shows. How would I create the view for admins to approve comments and then have the comments rendered in the guest user view when approved?

Also, I should mention that comments can be made by anonymous users – a user does not have to be signed up or logged in.

Would appreciate any guidance on this. I can provide more code if required. Thanks.

Comment: Why do users need pins? What not only use an approved_timestamp instead? If someone proved, you will know if it is and when it was approved. If you truly need to know who approved, you can go with 2 fields approved_timestamp, approved_by_id (or something similar)

Comment: As lcguida stated, it is good form to use a timestamp instead of a boolean.  This is something I learned many years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do this is like this:

```
(current_user.try(admin?) ? @pin.comments : @pin.comments.approved).each do |comment|
```